# Redmine Internal Error account and admin

Tags: apache, redhat, redmine

I get and internal error message page when I click Register and several other pages if I log in. Internal Error on admin, 
-Stylesheets are not showing if I log into the account and go to certain pages that deal with account. They do show correctly on projects,

Any thoughts on where to begin looking into this issue? At a lost on where to start on this one.

Internal error
An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.

where would the log files be located for this?

I am on Red Hat 7.4 using apache

A little more research, it seems to be related to going into anything related to account information, specifically these 2 areas:
http://xxxredmine/my/account
http://xxxredmine/admin

I have found this error message:

```
App 7394 stderr: Started GET "/projects" for 10.114.25.10 at 2018-05-02 14:53:55 -0400
App 7394 stderr: Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
App 7394 stderr:   Current user: anonymous
App 7394 stderr:   Rendered projects/index.html.erb within layouts/base (4.2ms)
App 7394 stderr: Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 11.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
App 7394 stderr: Started GET "/account/register" for 10.114.25.10 at 2018-05-02 14:54:00 -0400
App 7394 stderr: Processing by AccountController#register as HTML
App 7394 stderr:   Current user: anonymous
App 7394 stderr:   Rendered account/register.html.erb within layouts/base (4.7ms)
App 7394 stderr: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
App 7394 stderr:
App 7394 stderr: ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/www/redmine/tmp/cache/E6F):
App 7394 stderr:     22:
App 7394 stderr:     23:
App 7394 stderr:     24: <% unless @user.force_default_language? %>
App 7394 stderr:     25: <p><%= f.select :language, lang_options_for_select %></p>
App 7394 stderr:     26: <% end %>
App 7394 stderr:     27:
App 7394 stderr:     28: <% if Setting.openid? %>
App 7394 stderr:   lib/redmine/i18n.rb:125:in `languages_options'
App 7394 stderr:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1180:in `lang_options_for_select'
App 7394 stderr:   app/views/account/register.html.erb:25:in `block in _app_views_account_register_html_erb__4280574302093872533_47282631967020'
App 7394 stderr:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1190:in `labelled_form_for'
App 7394 stderr:   app/views/account/register.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_account_register_html_erb__4280574302093872533_47282631967020'
App 7394 stderr:   lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
App 7394 stderr:
App 7394 stderr:
```

Comment: issue resovled: http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/52749

Comment: To allow others to also discover your solution to this issue too, you could (or better: should) add the solution as an answer to your own question. Please describe in the answer what you did to resolve your issue instead of merely linking elsewhere.